# How to get Itemize not to skip the first line

Tags: margins, itemize, line-spacing

I have something like this in my cv template, I have tried to explain what the problem is below.

```
\NewEntry{2000}{blah}

\Description{\MarginText{blah} \begin{itemize} \item With itemize
\item It starts lower
\end{itemize} }

%------------------------------------------------

\NewEntry{2000}{blah}

\Description{\MarginText{blah}\textbullet \ I would like the text to start here, on the same line as \emph{blah} \\
\textbullet \ But using itemize}
```

[image]

Basically it boils down to the fact that the \itemize environment skips the first line, but I would like it not to because I want the first \item to be aligned with the margin text.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to achieve this? Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Please provide us with a complete, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that includes "your CV template". We don't know how `\NewEntry` and `\Description` is defined.

Comment: Sure, thanks for pointing it out. [Here](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/classicthesis-styled-cv) it is. I added the itemize environment myself, it wasn't part of the original template.

Comment: You can edit your question to include your MWE here. Please read the link Werner provided to figure out what needs to be in your MWE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose you a solution changing the definition for `\MarginText` so instead of `\marginpar` it uses `\marginnote` from the [`marginnote`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/marginnote) package; simply now move \MarginText just after the first `\item`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\reversemarginpar % Move the margin to the left of the page 
\usepackage{marginnote}

% Modified from the original to use \marginnote instead of \marginpar
% requires the marginnote package
\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginnote{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}} % New command defining the margin text style

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} % Use the classicthesis style for the style of the document
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita} % Use the currvita style for the layout of the document

\renewcommand{\cvheadingfont}{\LARGE\color{Maroon}} % Font color of your name at the top

\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for adding links   and customizing them
\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks, urlcolor=Maroon, linkcolor=Maroon} % Set link colors

\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{Spring 2011} % Set the width of the date box in each block

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{\noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \parbox{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}\hspace{1.5em} #2 #3 % Define a command for each new block - change spacing and font sizes here: #1 is the left margin, #2 is the italic date field and #3 is the position/employer/location field
\vspace{0.5em}} % Add some white space after each new entry

\newcommand{\Description}[1]{\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0\noindent\raggedright\footnotesize{#1}\par\normalsize\vspace{1em}} % Define a command for descriptions of each entry - change spacing and font sizes here

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty} % Stop the page count at the bottom of the first page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{cv}{\spacedallcaps{John Smith}}\vspace{1.5em} % Your name

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Personal Information}\vspace{0.5em} % Personal information heading

\NewEntry{}{\textit{Born in Canada,}}{20 November 1987} % Birthplace and date

\NewEntry{email}{\href{mailto:john@smith.com}{john@smith.com}} % Email address

\NewEntry{website}{\href{http://www.johnsmith.com}{http://www.johnsmith.com}} % Personal website

\NewEntry{phone}{(H) +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ (M) +1 (000) 111 1112} % Phone number(s)

\vspace{1em} % Extra white space between the personal information section and goal

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Goal}\vspace{1em} % Goal heading, could be used for a quotation or short profile instead

\Description{Gain fundamental experience in my area of interest and expertise.}\vspace{2em} % Goal text

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\noindent\spacedlowsmallcaps{Work Experience}\vspace{1em}

\NewEntry{2012--Present}{1\textsuperscript{st} Year Analyst, \textsc{Lehman Brothers}}

\Description{\MarginText{Lehman Brothers}Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (ags, oils, precious and base metals), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping. \\ Reference: John \textsc{McDonald}\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ +1 (000) 111 1111\ \ $\cdotp$\ \ \href{mailto:john@lehman.com}{john@lehman.com}}

\Description{\begin{itemize}
\item \MarginText{Lehman Brothers}First.
\item Second.
\item Third.
\item Fourth.
\end{itemize}
}

\end{cv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In fact, using `\marginnote` makes more sense than `\marginpar` (in my opinion), since the later is a kind of float and might end in an undesired location (a different page), whereas the former will not float away.

Comment: I was about to edit my question with the MWE, but you beat me to it! This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much.

Comment: @EmilioFerrucci You're welcome.